# Decorate the Port class from twisted.internet.udp

Tags: python, protocols, twisted, twisted.internet

Is there any possibility to decorate the Port class from twisted.internet.udp ?
I would like to modify the behavior of some methods of the Port class so that it
looses or duplicates ... or delays packets from time to time. 
My goal is to "simulate" some perturbation and to test if my own protocol (designed
above UDP) behaves correctly.

Any idea ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you'd *subclass* rather than *decorate*. Have you looked into the source?

Comment: No.  Please don't subclass these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to decorate or subclass or modify the behavior of the `udp.Port` class in any way except by submitting patches upstream to Twisted. For one thing, this class really should have been made private; it was never intended for public use, it's an implementation detail of the `IReactorUDP` interface.

Second, it's not the *only* such implementation detail within Twisted.  See also `twisted.internet.iocpreactor.udp.Port`, which doesn't share much of its implementation.

What you want to do is to simply write a wrapper that implements the same interface - something that implements [`IUDPTransport`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IUDPTransport.html) - and then do `self.transport = MyPacketDelayingWrapper(self.transport)` in your [`DatagramProtocol`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.protocol.DatagramProtocol.html).

Comment: For testing, you don't want a wrapper.  You want a brand new implementation of `IUDPTransport` that implements the behavior you want.  A wrapper will also inherit all of the delays and losses of the actual implementation, which will make it impossible to reliably test the specific cases you want.